# Logstash parsing different action with different logs

Tags: parsing, logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using Logstash to parse logs.

Now I want to handle the logs that match a particular regex differently and those which dont differently.

Is is achievable by Logstash.

How do I go about it?

My configuration file is:

```
input {
stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }
}
filter {

  grok {
    type => "stdin-type"
    patterns_dir=>["./patterns"]
    pattern => "%{PARSE_ERROR}"
    add_tag=>"%{type1},%{type2},%{slave},ERR_SYSTEM"
  }
date
{
replace=>["%{ts}","yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
custom_timestamp=>[%{ts}]
}

mutate
{
    type=>"stdin-type"
    replace => ["@message", "%{message}" ]

}


}
output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}
  elasticsearch
{ 
}
}
```

Say that I dont want to put those logs in elastic search which do not match a regex. Is it possible? How?

Comment: What do you want to do with logs that don't match? Drop them or output them somewhere else?

Comment: @nickethier I want to drop them in one project, and in the other associate some different tags with it and output them to the elastic search as well...kindly explain me both

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with conditionals either in your filter{} section or the output{} section:

```
filter {
    if [field] == "value" {
        drop{}
    }
}
```

or

```
output {
     if [field] != "value" {
         elasticsearch {
              ...
         }
     }
}
```